# How do I create a gallery page?

Tags: gallery

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to make a photo gallery page. I hope I can explain it in a way everyone can understand. I have alot of galleries on my site and I would like to display them on one page and have one image as a link to open that gallery post. Like the gallery on this theme http://themes.devilcantburn.com/stereoline/gallery/.

I'm kinda new to wordpress and not sure what the best way of displaying the galleries are, someone suggested creating a page template, which I tried but i was too complicted for me to work out how to add the images to the links. I would prefer to use coding rather then a plugin but at this point i'm willing to try anything as long as i get the result i need.

I like the way my galleries currently display on my site, but not the way they are displayed when your searching through them. (http://bgpworld.com/?cat=157). If anyone has a solution I would be really grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try to install the NextGEN gallery plugin.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

With it, you can easily achieve the page you want. Once installed, create a few galleries and upload your pictures. You can order your single galleries into albums. On the pages listing the galleries and the albums, you can see their unique ID.

Look the codes here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/
You can list single galleries, albums, slideshows of a gallery, and a lot more.

Paste the codes on in a page or post in the editor where you want them to appear, changing the gallery/album ID to the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

The link above dones't work, with that said have you tried the default galleries on wordpress? More information available here:http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages, using this you won't have to use a plugin as everything is already built in for you.